# Proof of asymptotic normality of Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE)

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, maximum-likelihood

I am a self-learner trying to understand the proof of asymptotic normality of Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) from the notes at http://www.konstantinkashin.com/notes/stat/Maximum_Likelihood_Estimation.pdf (pp. 25).

I am having certaing difficulties understanding how this converges in distribution to normal distribution

$\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta_{MLE}-\theta_o)=-\frac{\sqrt{n}l'(\theta_o)}{l''(\tilde \theta)}\xrightarrow{d}N(0, \frac{nI_n(\theta_o)}{(-I_n(\theta_o))^2})=N(0,\frac{n}{In(\theta_o)})$

if it was stated that nominator converges to normal distribution and denominator converges in probability to Fisher information.

I would be thankful for a simple as possible (mathematical) explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to combine the two results
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n} \ell'(\theta) &\overset{d}{\to} N(0, n I_n(\theta))
\\
\ell''_n(\tilde{\theta}) &\overset{a.s.}{\to} -I_n(\theta_0)
\end{align}
to arrive at your claim, you just need to apply [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem), which appears in the appendix of your linked notes.

Comment: In addition, for a single observation, how it is possible that the mean of the score is distributed as a normal with variance $\frac{I_1(\theta)}{n}$ (pp. 24, second expression from the bottom)? Shouldn't $n$ be equal to 1 then?