# Multiplying the Fisher Information by n to find the asymptotic variance

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, parametric, central-limit-theorem, maximum-likelihood

I've noticed that in some places, the asymptotic variance of a Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE) under certain regularity conditions is listed as $\frac{1}{I(\Theta )}$.

However, it's also commonly listed as $\frac{1}{nI(\Theta )}$ in other texts. Why is the fisher information multiplied by $n$ in some contexts but not in others?

Example:

This question from stackexchange: [Proof of asymptotic normality of Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584670/proof-of-asymptotic-normality-of-maximum-likelihood-estimator-mle)

versus

Page 6 from these notes: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lecture3.pdf

Comment: If $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ where $X_i$s are i.i.d,  then infomation contained in the sample $X$ can be calculated as $I_X(\theta)=nI_{X_i}(\theta)$. Here $I_{X_i}$ is information contained in any single observation $X_i$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks. Just to confirm.. so when the fisher information is calculated as $I(\Theta ) = -E({logf(x;\Theta )}'')$, that's for the information in a single observation $X_{i}$ correct? And then multiplying by $n$ gives the information for all the observations?

Comment: In the asymptotic variance $1/I(\theta)$,  Fisher information for one observation is considered.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks